# Is there a programming language that would have:

Tags: java, c++, oop, programming-languages

I am curious about such thing... Is there a programming language that would have:

- syntax such as Java and/or C++
- templates/generics support
- memory management (no garbage collection)
- "clean syntax" (no mess like perl or c/c++)
- "normal" OOP (polyphormism, interfaces, abstract classes, overloading and etc.)
- (preferably) compiles to machine code
- namespace support
- exception support
- no source preprocessor (as is in c\c++)
- statically typed

Comment: So basically Java without GC, that preferably compiles to machine code?

Comment: "clean syntax" is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: also consider c#, it is pretty much like java and c/c++ but much cleaner than both. you can do your own memory management if you like but it does have a GC.

Comment: why dont you create one :) , just find the best language for the job :)

Comment: What is wrong whit c++? Is it because it has some fieture (preprocessor)

Comment: Your requirements are mutually exclusive.  I see you want "syntax like C++" (#1) and "no syntax like C++" (#4).  Of course there are no right answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Vala](http://live.gnome.org/Vala) - designed as unmanaged C# for gnome
- D - Built on c but simpler than C++. I think it has some kind of GC though
- The new versions of Delphi, doesn't have curly brace syntax though

Answer (score 6):

Maybe [ADA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_%28programming_language%29) ? I can advice you to learn C/C++ or Java or something else and use it **smartly** - then you'll get **everything** you need.

UPD: You may be interested by [D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28programming_language%29)

Comment: I took a look at D before and I thought it has only GC support. But it seems that you can manage memory there manually...

Comment: Actually Ada also makes use of a GC.

Answer (score 5):

> - syntax such as Java and/or **C++**
> - "clean syntax" (no mess like perl or c/**c++**)

So, basically you want syntax such as C++, but you don't want syntax such as C++. It should be obvious that such a language cannot possibly exist, since the intersection of the set of languages that have syntax such as C++ and the set of languages that do not have syntax such as C++ must necessarily be the empty set.

There also some other requirements that don't make sense, like this one:

> - (preferably) compiles to machine code

What the compiler produces as its output is a trait of the compiler, it has nothing to do with the language. *Every* language can be compiled to *every other* language, provided the target language has at least the same computational power as the source language. (Which typically means that the target language must be Turing-complete, since most source language are Turing-complete.)

Answer (score 4):

What is your need for those features? Or are they things you think you need? Why not find a syntax you think you'll feel comfortable with, since that seems to be the most important thing in your list, and then explore your other **application requirements**

Comment: I am very comfortable with Java syntax. The thing is that I think that one could benefit from machine code and memory management. I am doing something like research now x)

Comment: @Tadas: Well, have fun corrupting your memory. Programmers being lazy bastards is only one reason GC is great, the other one is that everyone screws it up again and again. Also, machine code won't make horrible algorithms go (notably) faster or anything.

Comment: @delnan What it is supposed to mean? I asked question and yet you are going around with some assumptions. And so... Bad algorithms will still be bad, but as compared to Java you won't be stuck on heap only space with simple classes. Are you implying that C++ programmers cannot create programs without corrupting memory?

Comment: @Tadas: I just question if manual memory management and native compilation are desirable. The former is hard to get right (obviously, the programs we use daily that are written in C++ get it right, but they existed for years and were written by experienced programmers with much care), and while the latter does add *some* performance, it won't matter for 90% of all applications (especially because a clever JVM can get pretty close to C/C++ performance).

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting you'll have a hard time finding a language that meets all your criteria. However, these may be worth looking into:

- [Go](http://golang.org/). Clean syntax, compiles to machine code. Has GC, though. And isn't strictly O-O.
- [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) addresses many, but not all, of your issues (as mentioned by others in this thread).
- [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/). Functional, not O-O. But worth looking at anyway.
- [D](http://www.digitalmars.com/), also as mentioned by others.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely Scala. It confirms all your points

Comment: Scala is on the JVM , so it uses the GC , he dont want that

Answer (score 0):

You only get GC issues if you discard objects.  Write your application to recycle object instead and you won't have any garbage collection.

You can design an application which only GC's over night for example. i.e. zero-cost during the day, but some garbage is allowed.

Perhaps you could say what your concern is with having a GC.  There may be ways to work around the problem which opens up languages like C# and Java.

BTW: Java and C# is compiled to machine code at run time.

Answer (score 0):

To put it bluntly: Learn C++ and use it the way it should be used.

Done.

Comment: Each language has it's advantages and disadvantages, but it's up to developer to elevate ones and endure others. So why shouldn't you leave that decision to me what and how to use? Question isn't about one or other way to use some language.